# The function y[x] does not have the same number of arguments as independent variables

Tags: differential-equations

What is the problem with my code? I did google the error, but I didn't find anything useful. Could someone please help me?

```
Dd = 1/2;
v0 = 3;
rho = 1;
pr0 = Cos[Pi/6] rho;
pt0 = Sin[Pi/6] rho;
pt0 = 1;
Drp = 0;

DSolve[
  {y[x] + x y'[x] == v0 pr[x]/Dd + x v0 pr'[x]/Dd, 
   (4 v0 pr0 x + Dd) pr[x] + v0 x^2 y[x]/2 + (2 v0 x^2 pr0 - Dd x) pr'[x] - 
     x^2 Dd pr''[x] == 0}, 
  y, pr, x]
```

Numeric method:

```
L = 50;
EQ = 
  {y[x] + x y'[x] == v0 pr[x]/Dd + x v0 pr'[x]/Dd, 
   (4 v0 pr0 x + Dd) pr[x] + v0 x^2 y[x]/2 + (2 v0 x^2 pr0 - Dd x) pr'[x] - 
     x^2 Dd pr''[x] == 0, 
   y[L] == 1, pr[L] == pr0, y'[L] == v0 pr[L]/Dd, 
   pr'[L] == v0 (pr0 pr[L] + y[L]/2)/Dd}

sol = NDSolve[EQ, {pr, y}, {x, 10^-6, 4}];
```

Comment: dsolve takes 3 arguments, you have supplied 4. Why that particular (misleading) error message is a bit of a puzzle.

Comment: why are you specifying conditions at `L=50` which is not even in the solution domain?

Comment: I have forgotten to change solution domain to L. @george2079

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `{y,pr}` inside DSolve:

```
DSolve[{y[x] + x y'[x] ==v0 pr[x]/Dd + x v0 pr'[x]/Dd, 
(4 v0 pr0 x + Dd) pr[x]+v0 x^2 y[x]/2 + (2 v0 x^2 pr0 - Dd x) pr'[x] - x^2 Dd pr''[x] ==0}
, {y, pr}, x]
```

MMA can't solve these ode's !

But you can try to separate the two odes: 
Solving the second equation for y and substituting the result in the first equation gives

```
dgln = {y[x] + x y'[x] ==v0 pr[x]/Dd + x v0 pr'[x]/Dd, (4 v0 pr0 x + Dd) pr[x] +v0 x^2 y[x]/2 + (2 v0 x^2 pr0 - Dd x) pr'[x] - x^2 Dd pr''[x] == 0}
ergy = Solve[dgln[[2]], y[x]][[1]]
odepr=Simplify[  dgln[[1]] /. ergy /. D[ergy, x]] (* ode in pr[x] *)
```

which can be solved with DSolve

```
DSolve[dgln[[1]] /. ergy /. D[ergy, x], pr, x]
```

Semi analytical solution contains DifferentialRoot[] ...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by  `D x`?

Comment: Is ir possible to solve it numeric?

Comment: @WatWatson first answer what is `D`

Comment: @george2079 It is a typo. It is Dd.

Comment: ok, I fixed that.

Comment: For a numerical solution you should provide all boundary conditions...

Comment: I did but I can not solve the eqution@UlrichNeumann

Comment: Would you please plot the result? I can not understand the output

Comment: @Wat Watson: the boundary conditions should be explicit! The boundary `y'[L]==...` is incorrect and must be removed!

Comment: or could you solve the equation numerically? I have added my code to solve it numerically

Comment: But I should provide the derivative of functions for the bounday condition because it is second order equation. What is wrong with that?

Comment: The max-order of y is y'[x]!

Answer (score 0):

here is a working system. Your system is only first order in `y` so you can not specify both `y` and `y'`.

Also your initial conditions must be given explicitly, ie where `pr[L]` appears on the right you need to substitute `pr0` etc.

```
L = 50;

EQ = {
   y[x] + x y'[x] == v0 pr[x]/Dd + x v0 pr'[x]/Dd ,
   (4 v0 pr0 x + Dd) pr[x] + 
     v0 x^2 y[x]/2 + (2 v0 x^2 pr0 - Dd x) pr'[x] - x^2 Dd pr''[x] == 
    0,
   y[L] == 1,
   pr[L] == pr0,
   pr'[L] == v0 (pr0 pr0 + 1/2)/Dd};
sol = NDSolve[EQ, {pr, y}, {x, 10^-6, L}];

LogPlot[{-y[t], -pr[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]